# Remove Duplicate cells in a table

Tags: excel, openoffice-calc, vba

I searched a way to remove duplicate cells through a table leaving only one unique element for the entire table.
The problem is that it's not a list of elements (in a column) but they're spread through the table.
Anything I found delete duplicates within the column, or with a transposed table, within the row. I found nothing that can delete any duplicate in different columns and rows simultaneously.
I saw that a conditional formatting for duplicates in excel, selecting the entire table, result in every multiple element to be formatted. The fact is that I can't delete all the correct formatted cells because I need one element for each case.
How can I do that? I'm guessing "normal" excel and any spreadsheet software aren't enough, do I need to use VBA for excel or something else?
I also thought on using something like MS Word to remove duplicates, but elements have spaces on them and sometimes they have exact "adjectives" that can ruin the results, That's why I need something that can remove the entire cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say we start with a table like:

[image]

This short macro loops through all the cells in the table and clears cells containing values that appear more than once:

```
Sub DupKiller()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range

    Set rng = Range("A1:J21")

    For Each r In rng
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, r) > 1 Then r.Clear
    Next r
End Sub
```

[image]

The routine will work for text as well as numbers.